# SQL Server Group only one category

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table in SQL Server 2019 named `Orders` with 5 columns: ID, Date, Customer Name, Total Amount, and Category.

I want to see all the orders, but I want orders in category `Food` to collect in a group and display in one row, while the other categories display every row 1 by 1. Only the `Food` category should be grouped; others should display individually.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

A `union` would be the simplest way to do this. That way you can group for the "Food" category and show row by row for everything else.

```
SELECT
    [ID]
    ,[Date]
    ,[Customer Name]
    ,[Total Amount]
    ,[Category]
FROM
    [ORDERS]
WHERE
    [Category] != 'Food'

UNION

SELECT
    NULL [ID]              -- or MAX([ID]) [ID]
    ,NULL [Date]            -- or MAX([Date]) [Date]
    ,NULL [Customer Name]   -- or 'All Food Customers' [Customer Name]
    ,SUM([Total Amount]) [Total Amount]
    ,[Category]
FROM
    [ORDERS]
WHERE
    [Category] = 'Food'
GROUP BY
    [Category]

ORDER BY
    [Category]
```